# Unable to connect from the host OS to the guest in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have an Ubuntu machine and I have installed 64-bit RHEL on VirtualBox.

I changed the adapter settings of the guest to connected to bridged network, and I am able to ping my host from the guest, but the opposite is not possible. Any clues?

Comment: +1 for asking on SU. Could you give the output of `ifconfig -a` on both the host and guest? This will help us diagnose the networking situation.

Answer (score 1):

Add a bridge group with `brctl`, add a tap interface to the bridge group with uml tools, and you should be good to go assuming the RHEL firewall isn't blocking ICMP.